# Передача вектора наследников

Tags: c++

Возникла следующая проблема: имеется базовый класс и класс наследника, требуется передать в функцию вектор наследников, но как вектор, содержащий базовые элементы. Функции незачем знать, что это вектор наследников. Вариант с вектором указателей не очень удобен, так как не хотелось бы добавлять выделение памяти и потом еще постоянное разыменование указателей. Подскажите, мб есть способ как это можно сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Point
{
public:
    Point(){}
};

class Node: public Point
{
public:
    Node() {}
};

void foo(std::vector<Point>& p)
{
}

int main()
{
std::vector<Point> a;
std::vector<Node> b;
foo(b);
}
```

Comment: В буквальной интерпретации задача не имеет решения: вектор наследников не является вектором баз и передать второе в качестве первого в принципе невозможно. Полиморфизм в контенерах возможен только при хранении в контейнерах указателей или ссылок на элементы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы избежать проблем с выделением/освобождением памяти можно использовать контейнер умных указателей. Пример:

```
using namespace std;

namespace test
{
  class Base
  {
  public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    Base(const Base& other) = default;
    Base& operator=(const Base& other) = default;

    Base(Base&& other) = default;
    Base& operator=(Base&& other) = default;

    virtual string whoami() { return "base"; }
  };

  class Derived_1 : public Base
  {
  public:
    virtual string whoami() { return "derived_1"; }
  };

  class Derived_2 : public Derived_1
  {
  public:
    virtual string whoami() final { return "derived_2"; }
  };

  vector<shared_ptr<Base>> make_collection()
  {
    const int count = 4;

    vector<shared_ptr<Base>> result;
    result.reserve(count);

    result.push_back(make_shared<Base>());
    result.push_back(shared_ptr<Base>(new Base()));
    result.push_back(shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived_1()));
    result.push_back(shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived_2()));

    return result;
  }

  void dump(const vector<shared_ptr<Base>>& collection)
  {
    for (auto it = collection.cbegin(), end = collection.cend(); it != end; ++it) {
      cout << (*it)->whoami() << endl;
    }
  }
}

int main (int, char**)
{
  auto collection = test::make_collection();
  test::dump(collection);
  return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
base
base
derived_1
derived_2
```

Answer (score 3):

Выбирайте, либо ссылки либо указатели, других способов нет. Кроме того, так просто у Вас передать вектор объектов типа `Node` в функцию, которая ожидает объекты типа `Point` не получится, даже если добавить ссылки/указатели — придётся делать копию. Т.е. Ваш код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
void foo(std::vector<Point&>& p)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> a;
    std::vector<Node> b;
    foo(std::vector<Point&>{b.begin(), b.end()});
}
```